# Using Firebase Auth with Django

Tags: django, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to use firebase authentication for my django webapp. To achieve this, I think would I need to write a custom auth backend - is that right? I don't see any libraries that already do this - django-allauth looks like it comes pretty close as an alternative but I am interested in the phone number verification provided by firebase.

I'm also confused about what happens to the User model and functions like `request.user` or `user.is_authenticated`. Right now I use the authenticate and login functions - how does `django` know that a user is logged in via `firebase`? Would I still be creating a User model for every user?

Thanks

Answer (score 25):

You can use Firebase Auth with any framework. You don't necessarily need to use custom auth. Typically, you would sign in the user on the client, get the ID token by calling `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()` and then pass the ID token to your server, verify it and parse its payload identifying the user ID and its other claims by using the Firebase Admin SDKs and then you can issue a session cookie identifying the user associated with that ID token.

On signout, you would clear that session cookie.

If you also need to persist that user on the backend after setting the session cookie, you can also use the Firebase Admin SDK to lookup a user identified by the user ID or just use the token claims to populate the user without any network call. You can populate that in the user model of associated framework if needed.

For more on session management, you can refer to this django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: So it sounds to me like you wouldn't use something like django-rest-auth with this?

Comment: Thanks for a great answer @bojeil, I'm attaching this link to a documentation that might be useful for others https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

Comment: @bojeil what do you mean by this line in your ans: verify it and parse its payload identifying the user ID and its other claims by using the Firebase Admin SDKs

Comment: Updated link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: this ID token is a token jwt?

Comment: The action of passing this ID token to Django is a risky move, do you have a snippet that can illustrate the encryption portion?