# Is there any way to use Firebase Phone authentication in Django?

Tags: python, django, firebase, firebase-authentication

I came to know about the Pyrebase. But it only offers email authentication. I need to use only Phone authentication. Users can login by verifying their OTP.

But there doesn't seem to be any proper guideline out there. Anyone want to elaborate this topic little more? Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Phone authentication with Firebase has the same logic and limits as the other providers, so see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48232029/using-firebase-auth-with-django

Comment: check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmHO7RDgE2A

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe pyrebase offers phone authentication, you can build custom tokens on it but for phone authentication through an OTP, I believe it would be easier if you deploy it using the firebaseUI, for further information, you can check out the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth